# recursive parsing in json and get the value using ansible

Tags: json, ansible, until-loop

I need to get the value of key in json from ansible play. Here is the issue is - Not sure the key will be in particular level of Json. It may vary from json to json. So, I need to 'serach' for the keys in json blindly and get the values for them [Not sure how many keys are avalible and how deep they are available]. Here I'm giving the sample json and play to achieve same.

JSON Data:

```html
{
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "errors": [
        {
            "jobname": "DbcAllJob_td_part_20190211150403_1",
            "errorList": [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "migrationId": "b9e19f6b-bc2e-4e2b-8fe9-20efb74d8289",
                    "jobId": "27",
                    "backupPhase": "DATA",
                    "restorePhase": "NULL",
                    "errorType": "ABORT",
                    "atTimeStamp": "2019/02/11 15:27:46",
                    "errorStatus": "UNRESOLVED",
                    "errorcode": "1148",
                    "errortext": "1148: DSA DSMAIN-BARNC Communication Exception: 1001:(**********K) recv() call has EOF",
                    "report": {
                        "root": {
                            "system": "TARGET",
                            "host": "**********",
                            "state_text": "2019/02/11 07:26:52.181 [      27:29152:29152] ERROR Executor - Exception received by master thread: recv() call has EOF",
                            "entityId": "**********_clienthandler",
                            "logTime": "2019/02/11 07:26:52.181",
                            "peers": [
                                "**********_clienthandler"
                            ],
                            "phase": "",
                            "rootError": "BarNC - User shutdown request from command line received, stopping BARNC",
                            "software": "clienthandler"
                        },
                        "sequence": [
                            {
                                "host": "sdt09586",
                                "state_text": "Feb 11 07:25:20 sdt09586 DSA[27578]: CRITICAL: DSA: 4751002 #CRITICAL: DataStreamController: 4751002 #DSC version[16.20.24.00], Commons version[16.20.24.00], DSC  cannot connect to activeMQ Broker.",
                                "entityId": "sdt09586_messages",
                                "logTime": "2019/02/11 7:25:20.000",
                                "peers": [],
                                "phase": "",
                                "software": "messages"
                            },
                            {
                                "system": "SOURCE",
                                "host": "**********",
                                "state_text": "Feb 11 07:26:52 ********** Teradata[19593]: INFO: Teradata: 6670 # DSMAIN 1148: DSA DSMAIN-BARNC Communication Exception: 1001:(**********K) recv() call has EOF",
                                "entityId": "**********_messages",
                                "logTime": "2019/02/11 7:26:52.000",
                                "peers": [],
                                "phase": "",
                                "software": "messages"
                            },
                            {
                                "system": "SOURCE",
                                "host": "**********",
                                "state_text": "Feb 11 07:26:52 ********** Teradata[6369]: INFO: Teradata: 3265 #Transaction has been Aborted by Administrator or Operations Staff.",
                                "entityId": "**********_messages",
                                "logTime": "2019/02/11 7:26:52.000",
                                "peers": [],
                                "phase": "",
                                "software": "messages"
                            },
                            {
                                "system": "SOURCE",
                                "host": "**********",
                                "state_text": "2019/02/11 07:26:52.900 (134226672): Exception rethrown caught in DSMBackupTask::BeginWriteTask.",
                                "entityId": "27_**********_barlog_26623_34_3_3",
                                "logTime": "2019/02/11 07:26:52.900",
                                "peers": [
                                    "AMP =1"
                                ],
                                "phase": "",
                                "software": "barlog_26623_34_3_3"
                            },
                            {
                                "system": "SOURCE",
                                "host": "**********",
                                "state_text": "2019/02/11 07:26:52.900 (134226672): SendInternalAbort assumeMsgFromStpAab = 1",
                                "entityId": "27_**********_barlog_26623_34_3_3",
                                "logTime": "2019/02/11 07:26:52.900",
                                "peers": [
                                    "AMP =1"
                                ],
                                "phase": "",
                                "software": "barlog_26623_34_3_3"
                            },
                            {
                                "system": "SOURCE",
                                "host": "**********",
                                "state_text": "2019/02/11 07:26:52.900 (134226672): SendInternalAbort, partition = 34, jobId = 27",
                                "entityId": "27_**********_barlog_26623_34_3_3",
                                "logTime": "2019/02/11 07:26:52.900",
                                "peers": [
                                    "AMP =1"
                                ],
                                "phase": "",
                                "software": "barlog_26623_34_3_3"
                            },
                            {
                                "system": "SOURCE",
                                "host": "**********",
                                "state_text": "2019/02/11 07:26:52.900 (134226672): errorCode = 1148, errorTextLength = 84, errorText = 1148: DSA DSMAIN-BARNC Communication Exception: 1001:(**********K) recv() call has EOF",
                                "entityId": "27_**********_barlog_26623_34_3_3",
                                "logTime": "2019/02/11 07:26:52.900",
                                "peers": [
                                    "AMP =1"
                                ],
                                "phase": "",
                                "software": "barlog_26623_34_3_3"
                            },
                            {
                                "system": "SOURCE",
                                "host": "**********",
                                "state_text": "2019/02/11 07:26:52.910 (134254672): AbortTask has a message...",
                                "entityId": "27_**********_barlog_26623_34",
                                "logTime": "2019/02/11 07:26:52.910",
                                "peers": [],
                                "phase": "DATA/BUILD",
                                "software": "barlog_26623_34"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "remedy": [
                        {
                            "seqNum": 1,
                            "remedy": "Configure all machines to have same bynet configuration",
                            "remedyOpcode": "RECONFIGURE_BYNET",
                            "remedyInfo": [
                                {
                                    "systemName": "**********",
                                    "ipAddress": "**********",
                                    "username": "**********",
                                    "password": "**********",
                                    "osUser": "root"
                                },
                                {
                                    "systemName": "**********",
                                    "ipAddress": "**********",
                                    "username": "**********",
                                    "password": "**********",
                                    "osUser": "root"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "seqNum": 2,
                            "remedy": "Bring ClientHandler up on **********",
                            "remedyOpcode": "RESTART_SERVICE",
                            "remedyInfo": {
                                "systemName": "**********",
                                "ipAddress": "**********",
                                "username": "**********",
                                "password": "**********",
                                "osUser": "root"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "seqNum": 3,
                            "remedy": "Re-submit the job",
                            "remedyOpcode": "RESUBMIT",
                            "remedyInfo": null
                        }
                    ],
                    "detailedreport": [
                        {
                            "component": "TPANode : **********",
                            "description": "TPANODE status : Up and Running",
                            "additionalProperties": {}
                        },
                        {
                            "component": "TPANode : **********",
                            "description": "TPANODE status : Up and Running",
                            "additionalProperties": {}
                        },
                        {
                            "component": "Bynet : [**********, **********]",
                            "description": "Bynet configuration mismatch",
                            "additionalProperties": {}
                        },
                        {
                            "component": "ClientHandler : **********",
                            "description": "ClientHandler status : not running",
                            "additionalProperties": {}
                        },
                        {
                            "component": "ActiveMQ : **********",
                            "description": "ActiveMQ status : running",
                            "additionalProperties": {}
                        },
                        {
                            "component": "ActiveMQ Queue: **********",
                            "description": "ActiveMQ message count : 13",
                            "additionalProperties": {}
                        },
                        {
                            "component": "DSC : **********",
                            "description": "DSC status : running, DSARest status : running",
                            "additionalProperties": {}
                        },
                        {
                            "component": "DSC Processes: **********",
                            "description": "Number of DSC processes running : 1",
                            "additionalProperties": {}
                        },
                        {
                            "component": "DSMAIN : **********",
                            "description": "DSMain status : Up and Running, Left over Processes : No left over processes",
                            "additionalProperties": {}
                        },
                        {
                            "component": "DSMAIN : **********",
                            "description": "DSMain status : Up and Running, Left over Processes : No left over processes",
                            "additionalProperties": {}
                        },
                        {
                            "component": "DatabaseConnection : **********",
                            "description": "Database status : UP",
                            "additionalProperties": {}
                        },
                        {
                            "component": "DatabaseConnection : **********",
                            "description": "Database status : UP",
                            "additionalProperties": {}
                        },
                        {
                            "component": "DatabaseConnection : **********",
                            "description": "Database status : UP",
                            "additionalProperties": {}
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "migrationId": "b9e19f6b-bc2e-4e2b-8fe9-20efb74d8289",
                    "jobId": "27",
                    "backupPhase": null,
                    "restorePhase": null,
                    "errorType": "ABORT",
                    "atTimeStamp": "",
                    "errorStatus": null,
                    "errorcode": "1160",
                    "errortext": "An error occurred restoring statistics.",
                    "report": {
                        "root": null,
                        "sequence": null
                    },
                    "remedy": [
                        {
                            "seqNum": -1,
                            "remedy": null,
                            "remedyOpcode": null,
                            "remedyInfo": null
                        }
                    ],
                    "detailedreport": [
                        {
                            "component": null,
                            "description": null,
                            "additionalProperties": {}
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

From above json I need to read the 'remedy' values. But not sure at what level they are available always.

Here is the ansible script for the same.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:

  - name: loop
    set_fact:
       migration_detail_status: "{{ lookup('file', 'inj_error.json') }}"
    until: "'{{ migration_detail_status.errors.0.errorList.0.remedy.1.remedy | search('Bring ClientHandler up on') }}' and '{{ migration_detail_status.errors.0.errorList.0.remedy.1.remedyOpcode | search('RESTART_SERVICE') }}'"
    retries:  2
    delay: 5
    ignore_errors: yes

  - debug:
        var: migration_detail_status.errors.0.errorList.0.remedy.1.remedyOpcode
```

At `until` condition I've traversed over json as I know the format of json. but, it may not be same for all the cases. So, please help to traverse to get the searching `key:value` from json irrespective of their level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of all `remedy`'s with JMESPath query: `errors[].errorList[].remedy[].remedy`.

```
[
  "Configure all machines to have same bynet configuration",
  "Bring ClientHandler up on **********",
  "Re-submit the job"
]
```

In Ansible you would use `json_query` filter to apply JMESPath queries.

If you also need opcodes: `errors[].errorList[].remedy[].{r:remedy,o:remedyOpcode}`

```
[
  {
    "r": "Configure all machines to have same bynet configuration",
    "o": "RECONFIGURE_BYNET"
  },
  {
    "r": "Bring ClientHandler up on **********",
    "o": "RESTART_SERVICE"
  },
  {
    "r": "Re-submit the job",
    "o": "RESUBMIT"
  },
  {
    "r": null,
    "o": null
  }
]
```

Example:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ migration_detail_status | json_query('errors[].errorList[].remedy[].remedy') }}"
```

Comment: Thanks konstantin. Can you please post the syntax/code used to get the all remedy's in the json.

Comment: Here I found another issue like with multiple conditions at until block.   `until: "'{{ migration_detail_status | json_query('errors[].errorList[].remedy[].remedy') | join('\n') | search('Bring ClientHandler up on')}}' and '{{ migration_detail_status | json_query('errors[].errorList[].remedy[].remedyOpcode') | join('\n') | search('NOTHING####XXXX')}}'"`  . Even for negative-condition its passing. It supposed to fail with and condition as remedyOpcode doesnot have 'NOTHING####XXXX'

Comment: Can I've some pointers on it. Am I missing something.  It's working as expected with separate conditions.
`until: "{{ migration_detail_status | json_query('errors[].errorList[].remedy[].remedy') | join('\n') | search('Bring ClientHandler up on')}}`  - **Passing**                                                                                         `until: "{{ migration_detail_status | json_query('errors[].errorList[].remedy[].remedyOpcode') | join('\n') | search('RESTART_SERVICE_XXXX')}}` - **Failing**. But when I join both its passing again. It supposed to fail

Comment: Use my second query with `o:remedyOpcode`, then use `selectattr` filter to fetch required element with `search` test and compare resulting opcode. Sorry, but I will not do all the work for free.

Comment: hey.. thanks konstantin. Thanks alot for the pointers. I can proceed and go-ahead.